# Tomcat Virtual Host to prevent Improper-Input-Handling attack

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, vulnerabilities, vulnerability

I'm currently on the process of trying fix a site vulnerability, basically it is one type of the "Improper Input Handling" attack.

Let's say my website is  **www.mywebsite.com** 
and there is hacker's website **www.hacker.com**

whenever there is a request send to **www.mywebsite.com** with modified "`Host`" header point to **www.hacker.com**, my site will create a redirect to **www.mywebsite.com** along with whatever the url it was. 
e.g.

Normal:

```
Host: www.mywebsite.com 
GET  www.mywebsite.com/get/some/resources/
Reponse 200 ok
```

Hack:

```
Host: www.hacker.com (#been manually modified) 
GET  www.mywebsite.com/get/some/resources/
Response 302 
Send another Redirect to www.hacker.com/get/some/resources
```

My website is running on Tomcat 7, I tried some solution with set up the virtual host by point the unknown host to a `defaultlocalhost` which suppose to do nothing. but it still send the redirect for some reason.

Here attached is my `server.xml` host configure:

```
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="defaultlocalhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">  
<Host name="www.mywebsite.com"  appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="false" deployOnStartup="true">

    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
           prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
           pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
  </Host>

  <Host name="defaultlocalhost"  >

  </Host>
```

**So, my question is, Am I on the right track to prevent this kind of attack ? If yes, what I did wrong that still not working? (The ultimate goal is, if it is not the legit Host that been passed in, the request should be discard/ignored/return 404 but not redirect with 302**)

Thank you in advance.

More references about the attack here :
http://www.skeletonscribe.net/2013/05/practical-http-host-header-attacks.html

http://projects.webappsec.org/w/page/13246933/Improper%20Input%20Handling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh well, end up answer my own question.

After join the Tomcat user mailing list (subscribe email address: users@tomcat.apache.org).
There is the guy named Andre helped me get this resolved:

basically what I did wrong is missing `appBase` in my `defaultlocalhost`

```
  <Host name="defaultlocalhost" appbase="whatever" >

  </Host>
```

The above configure successfully returned 404 status whenever a illegal request was been send.  the reason is that whenever you don't set the `appbase` it always default to `webapps` so it essentially didn't do anything with my original configure.

Hope this can help anyone who had similar issue.

Comment: what we need to do to send 403 (un authorized) response instead of 404(not found)?